# Javassist dependent jar missing

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

I am trying to complete java instrumentation on my local glassfish server. When it tries to change the byte code I am getting

> Severe: javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>       at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:771)

To me this looked like a problem with the jar file I created but I checked the manifest.mf and included the maven dependency location. Any suggestions?

```
Premain-Class: com.agent.TestAgent
Agent-class: com.agent.TestAgent
Boot-Class-Path: D:/TEST_PROJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ C:/Users/djones/
Class-Path: D:/TEST_PROJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ C:/Users/djones/
```

Comment: Looks like according to oracle the URLs must be relative to the code base of the JAR file for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its unable to fetch servlet jar path.
add servlet jar path in your Boot-Class-Path , update it and try running it again

Answer (score 0):

I think Manifest file configuration is correct because control going to Premain-Class and doing  transform.My guess is may be the class showing in exception not present in jar file or some where.